# BASH : Print value of find command to a certain point & assign to a variable

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm trying to define a variable in 2 steps-

```
$ find /u01/app -name cmd_history.txt
```

which returns something like (for eg)

> /u01/app/refresh/db/18c/test/etc/cmd_history.txt

`$ export WORK_DIR=/u01/app/refresh/db/18c/test/etc`    (excluding /cmd_history.txt)

Basically, I want to achieve this in 1 single command i.e. feed the output of find to awk or cut & omit the  /cmd_history.txt.

```
$ export WORK_DIR=find /u01/app -name cmd_history.txt | awk or cut
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU `find`:

You can print the leading directories with `-printf '%h'` and quit `find` after the first match with `-quit`.

```
export WORK_DIR=$(find /u01/app -name 'cmd_history.txt' -printf '%h' -quit)
```

With BSD `find`:

Print the first match, then quit and get the parent directory with `dirname`.

```
export WORK_DIR=$(dirname "$(find /u01/app -name 'cmd_history.txt' -print -quit)")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution which does not need awk or cut:

```
WORK_DIR=$(find /u01/app -name cmd_history.txt)
export WORK_DIR=${WORK_DIR%/*}
```

${WORK_DIR%/*} removes last part : /cmd_history.txt

Here is an even simpler solution:

```
export WORK_DIR=$(find /u01/app -name cmd_history.txt -printf %h)
```

where **-printf %h** gives directly the directory.